# PDF.JS Extract Text from X and Y position?

Tags: javascript, text, coordinates, pdf.js

I made a simple function that will console.log the getTextContent() of one single page.
This will display all text of that PDF file page.

Is there a way to enter some X, Y coordinates (as well as Height and Width) and that the getTextContent() will only display the text that is inside the coordinates?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you got the solution? I am looking for the same

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this? I've same problem right now.

Comment: No sorry. I don't think it works.